# Adding player names to Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, user-input

I'm new to java and really struggling to add players (between 1-4) to an arraylist for a simple game. My thought is that the program opens by asking the user/s (from same computer, very basic) how many will be playing and to proceed by entering names. Once done the main menu will appear. I've rewritten the below for hours and just can't figure it out. I realise the playerTurn may have no place in this bit of code but I feel I've tried
everything I can think of. Please help!

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public int rounds;    // 5-30
    public int playerTurn; // to choose how many will be playing. 1-4
    public ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

    public Game() {

        System.out.println("Welcome to The Farm! Please enter how many will be playing today (1-4 players) by entering your names. When finished please enter menu to begin");
        String names = input.next();

        while (true) {
            for (int playerTurn = 0; playerTurn < 4; playerTurn++) {
                newPlayer(names);   // calls add player method

            }
        }
    }
```

```java
    public void newPlayer(String newPlayer) {
        players.add(new Player(newPlayer));
    }
```

Comment: Where is your newPlayer method?

Comment: public void newPlayer(String newPlayer) {

        players.add(new Player(newPlayer));
    }

Comment: Please add this to the code in your question. Optimally anyone should be able to just execute your code to reproduce the behaviour you are describing.

Comment: I see, sorry! Just been added.

Answer (score 0):

You seem confused.

First you need to read how many players will be playing.  You do that, but for some reason you assign it to `names`, and then you create a `Player` with it, which does not make sense.  And then you have to make a loop based on the number and at each iteration, you ask for a name and create a player.

```
public static void main() {
    int numOfPlayers = getNumOfPlayers();
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
    System.out.println("Enter the number of players");
    int numOfPlayers = reader.nextInt();
    
    if (numOfPlayers > 4) // display error message - exit 

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfPlayers; ++i) {
        String playerName = reader.nextLine();
        players.add(new Player(playerName));
    }
    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: I am very confused! I understand your point, I was just trying to figure out if the amount of players can be determined by the amount of names entered. Perhaps I can ask for names after the amount of players has been selected.

Comment: You can do that also, You just need to split the string.

for example, if you ask for names and the user enters: "name1, name2, name3", you can split it (names.split(",")) get the size of the array and there is your number of the players

Answer (score 0):

Your class constructor has an infinite loop (`while(true)`), so it just keeps adding `Player` instances until you terminate your program.

```
public class Game {
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Scanner reading from System.in
    private int rounds;    // 5-30
    private int playerAmount; // Indicating how many players take part
    private ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<>(); // Storing player instances

    public Game() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to The Farm! Please enter how many will be playing today (1-4 players) by entering your names. When finished please enter menu to begin");

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            String name = input.readLine();
            if (name.equals("menu") || players.size() >= 4) {
                break; // User entered menu or the there are already 4 players in the ArrayList -> break out of the for loop
            }
            newPlayer(name); // New player gets added if the if-condition above isn't executed
        }
        playerAmount = players.size();
    }
}
```

This way when you instantiate your Game class, the user will be prompted to enter player names, the for loop will execute only 4 times unless the input equals `"menu"` or when the maximum amount of players are reached.
At last the size of the ArrayList determines how many names have been entered, thus how many players are playing.